# CodeIgniter working fine on localhost, but routes doesn't work on web server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my web server it's not on root directory, it's in a subfolder called intranet.
So I've updated database settings and this configuration in config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/intranet/';
```

But there isn't a single route that is working, and it's working fine on localhost.
Is there any other thing that I must do to it work fine on my web server?

Comment: Maybe .htaccess issue?

Comment: @Shomz, just checked, it's a htaccess issue, it won't execute my htaccess files, is there any alternative to that or it's required that I've to be able to run htaccess files? Also, I have a folder assets, with js,css and images, I was using `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|img|static|css|js|robots\.txt)`to access it, do you know how do I do now to access them, without htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess is needed to get rid of that index.php in the url (among other things). I'd seriously recommend you to try to fix it rather than look for an alternative approach. Maybe your root htaccess is preventing you from opening /intranet?

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I guess my webhost company won't allow me to use it, if I cannot use it, then I would that be a problem to my project or do you think that there's alternatives?

Comment: You mean you can't modify .htaccess?

Comment: They disabled it on apache, also thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, man. Now that's a very rough situation. Although it *might* be possible to run the thing some way (with a lot of sacrifices and pain), I'd still strongly suggest you either upgrade your hosting package (if possible) or use another hosting company, because disabling .htaccess is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put this code in you .htaccess file and try it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /intranet/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem is that htaccess is disabled on apache.